# how to unpack list inside list and append to string in python?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have created a structure of a list:

```
data = [
[['name', 'date', 3] , 'text text text text'],
[['name', 'date', 5] , 'text text text text'],
[['name', 'date', 7] , 'text text text text'],
[['name', 'date', 8] , 'text text text text']
]
```

I  want it to be just this:

```
data = [
['name', 'date', 3 , 'text text text text'],
['name', 'date', 5 , 'text text text text'],
['name', 'date', 7 , 'text text text text'],
['name', 'date', 8 , 'text text text text']
]
```

I need to unwrap the first element.

Here is code, but i want it to be done using list comprehension:

```
final_res = list()
for x in data:
   res = list()
   for item in x[0]:
      res.append( item)
   final_res.append(res)
   final_res.append(x[1])
```

I only know this function print(*list) - it just unwraps and prints out.

Comment: The structure of `data` is invalid. And also structure of the expected output.

Comment: `[d[0]+d[1] for d in data]`

Comment: @JRodDynamite, yes i spotted the error, thx u for the feedback!

Answer (score 5):

[use `*` unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/):

```py
data = [[*a, b] for a,b in data]

print(data)
```

Output:

```
[['name', 'date', 3, 'text text text text'],
 ['name', 'date', 5, 'text text text text'],
 ['name', 'date', 7, 'text text text text'],
 ['name', 'date', 8, 'text text text text']]
```